# How does this current limiter work? - and why doesn't it?

Tags: current, voltage-regulator, schematics, buck

I have a generic Ebay DC-DC buck converter, and the current limiting circuit is not working. I find that such devices often suffer from this issue, so I figured I'd reverse-engineer it in hopes of figuring out the problem.

Below is the schematic I came up with by following traces on the board; and by measuring continuity. I believe it to be accurate.

[image: schematic]

Unfortunately, the current-limiting (upper) part of the schematic makes no sense to me. Could someone explain what is going on, please?

I see no reason to use a TS431 in full saturation; neither is it clear why the op-amp ground reference isn't connected to ground.

I assume the current-limiter achieves its objective via pin 2 of the XL4015. Perhaps the LED, in addition to indicating, serves to prevent lower voltages from the op-amp reaching the XL4015?

In addition, could anyone offer a possible explanation for the failure of the unit to operate correctly? Where should I begin troubleshooting?

Photos of the board:

[image: top of board]

[image: bottom of board]

[image]

EDIT: Fixed schematic and added the 0.05Ω resistor

Comment: Your tracing of the comparators/op-amps is not correct. The TS431 provides a reference that is more stable than the 78L05.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your schematic is notified complete. You are missing the current-sense circuitry.

Comment: This is the circuitry on the board that I have. If it's wrong, then that's the fault of the manufacturer. I simply drew what was there. I did say it made no sense. As far as I can tell, it is an accurate representation of this board.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany In what way is it "not correct"? Bear in mind that I have the board here in front of me, and you do not. Why do you think the schematic is wrong?

Comment: The op-amps also can't be connected correctly - inputs and outputs may be mixed.

Comment: Ahem. As I said, this is the board I have in front of me. And again, as I said, I realise it makes no sense. But, nevertheless, this appears to be how the damn thing is wired. I will add photos.

Comment: Judging by the lonely via we can see on the bottom side just above the 4 stripes at the bottom-left, that board has 1 or more internal layers which you haven't accounted for in your schematic.

Comment: @brhans You make a valid point. However, there seems to be no continuity between that point and any other point. If there was another layer, that via would go somewhere.

Comment: @brhans Also, I can see through the board using a bright light. There are no tracks leading away from that via. Good thinking though.

Comment: That via appears to be located in a position where it would connect to pin-4 of the 8-pin dual op-amp - coincidentally the pin which is almost always grounded for a single-supply ...

Comment: Yes. However, it is definitely not connected to ground. This is one of the insane things I mentioned in my original question.

Comment: Where is the 0R050 resistor in your schematic? It appears to be in the OUT- path and would provide current measurement feedback to the opamps. You've also drawn VOUT- as connected to ground when it's pretty clear from the pic that the pin on the screw terminal is not connected to that copper pour.

Comment: The 0R050 is not used here. It is used by a second board that screws into this one. It appears to be optional.

Comment: My schematic simply omits the resistor.

Comment: Your schematic also omits the connection between VOUT- and the pair of connected opamp inputs which you drew on the top-side board photo.

Comment: Agreed. I forgot to add that. I will modify the schematic.

Comment: @brhans I see now that the resistor is necessary for operation. It doesn't explain why the board is malfunctioning, but it does go some way to explaining why my schematic made no sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there are a few connections missing.  The low side current must be drawn through the 50m\$\Omega\$ resistor or through a printed trace that does something similar.

Here is a schematic (courtesy of [this](https://www.circuitsonline.net/forum/view/126415) site)  that is very similar, though not exact.

Note how the **two LM358 inputs are connected**, and of course the dual op-amp power supply is 5V and ground.

Your board has a '431 for the reference and a real current sense resistor, but is otherwise likely very similar.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your taking the time to find this. However, the op-amps on my board are NOT wired in this manner. Also, remember I didn't build this board - it is one I bought from Ebay, and the current limiting pot isn't working. Presumably the builders had some reason for what they did, and weren't just totally insane. I'm trying to understand [a] how the board I have works, and [b] why the board I have doesn't work...

Comment: With your modifications it is beginning to resemble the circuit above **much** more closely.

Comment: You know, I'm starting to see the resemblance now... Any idea why it might not be working?

Comment: Nope. Maybe make some measurements under power.